# 'Interesting' orthogonal martices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

I'm working with an algorithm that takes as part of its input an orthogonal matrix with real entries. I'm trying to understand how the specification of this matrix affects performance of the algorithm. It's very difficult to do this analytically, so I'm working experimentally for now.

I'm loking for examples of orthogonal matrices that are in some sense 'interesting' or 'extreme'. Obviously the identity matrix is one choice. Another example might be the matrix that is 'least sparse' in the sense that the sum of the absolute values of the entries is as large as possible (is there a name for this?). Another choice is a random sample from the Gaussian orthogonal ensemble.

Can anyone suggest some other examples?

Many thanks.

Comment: What does the algorithm do? To check for floating point errors I'd use matrices with both very small and very large components arranged so that 1) very small quantities are added to large ones, or 2)small quantities are inverted.

Comment: It's an implementation of the Unscented transform in statistics. I need to specify a square root of the identity matrix, but the question is which one? In theory it shouldn't matter much, in practice I think it might.

Comment: The Gaussian orthogonal ensemble is a distribution over symmetric matrices, not orthogonal matrices.

Comment: My mistake. Doubtless there are many ways to construct a random orthogonal matrix though. You could generate a matrix with uniformly distributed or Gaussian entries and apply Gram-Schmidt, for example.